# google app engine paging and cursor

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cursor, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to implement paging in my app on google app engine, using the python datastore api. My requirement is to display user data using infinite list. My current implementation is using cursor with something like this:

```
    //retrieve current_cursor
    all_data = my_data.all().order('-created')
    data = all_data.fetch(limit=10, start_cursor=current_cursor)
    current_cursor = all_data.cursor()
    //save current_cursor
```

From my understanding, cursor works on queried result_set, which saves the time of the subsequent queries (but not the first one), am I correct?

My concern is that if we have large amount of data, the first time query will still be too slow. To make the first time query faster, my thought is that, instead of querying all data, I'll break the query into multiple smaller ones, such as setting a filter with `('created >', certain_date)` and using cursor to fetch results within each set.

However, the drawback is I'll have to maintain the `certain_date` on my own and if not choosing it wisely, it might cost me with lots of database read.

So my question is, do I understand the cursor correctly? Also, are there better ways to use google datastore to support this or any suggestions in general to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557791/how-to-understand-cursor-correctly) help?  Are you actually experiencing performance problems?

Comment: Thanks! I did read the post earlier but still couldn't figure it out and still felt the first query took longer. Now it seems like it might be other things. I'll go back to check my codes.

Answer (score 2):

No, the first time query will not be slower. The advantage of using cursor is that it only processes the specific set, depending on cursor position and the limit, unlike to the Offset and limit combination which processes the whole data set and just show you the required portion.

> Query cursors allow an application to retrieve a query's results in convenient batches without incurring the overhead of a query offset.

Regarding suggestions, for pagination, cursor is the best option, other suggestions are to use [Projections](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries), try to make best use of memcache by using get_by_id.

Comment: Ah. So the first time it won't query the whole thing, but just the number of result I fetch? Seems like I was all wrong about it. Thanks. I'll also take a look at the Projections.